# SQLAlchemy retrieving a sorted list of top scoring messages, many to many - users messages

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to retrieve a sorted list of the top scoring thread start messages. The count of the score should simply be likes - dislikes on a message.

Currently not working though, the score is always 0 despite the amount of likes and dislikes a message has. The fault is probably in the "code to run" section below, as the rest seems to work, but I'm not entirely sure.

A user shall only be able to either like or dislike a message, so i made two separate relations for likes and dislikes between a user and a message. Thus I can pretty easily keep track of the action a user has made and I'm able to show the user what action it has taken in the UI.

Feel out of depth and I don't know if my approach is the best one, hopefully you can help me get on the right path and help out others that are making a like/dislike system. Appreciate all the help I get!

The tables:

```
like_table = db.Table('like', db.metadata,
    db.Column('user', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('message', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('message.id')))

dislike_table = db.Table('dislike', db.metadata,
    db.Column('user', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('message', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('message.id')))
```

The User class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    reg_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    likes = db.relationship('Message', secondary=like_table, back_populates = 'likers')
    dislikes = db.relationship('Message', secondary=dislike_table, back_populates = 'dislikers')

    def __init__(self, uname, password):
        self.username = uname
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)
        self.reg_date = datetime.utcnow()
```

The Message class:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(500))
    post_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    writer = db.Column(db.String(128))
    writer_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    thread_start = db.Column(db.Boolean) # if it's the start of a thread

    likers = db.relationship('User', secondary=like_table, back_populates = 'likes')
    dislikers = db.relationship('User', secondary=dislike_table, back_populates = 'dislikes')

    def __init__(self, text, writer, thread_start):
        self.text = text
        self.post_date = datetime.utcnow()
        self.writer = writer.username
        self.writer_id = writer.id
        self.thread_start = thread_start

    @hybrid_property
    def score(self):
       return func.count(Message.likers) - func.count(Message.dislikers)
```

Code to run (probably something wrong here):

```
top_voted_threads = db.session.query(Message, Message.score.label('total')).\
    filter(Message.thread_start == True).\
    join(Message.likers, aliased = True).join(Message.dislikers).\
    group_by(Message).order_by('total DESC')[0:10]
print(top_voted_threads)
```

Current output, scores are wrongly 0:

```
[(<app.Message object at 0x103f42278>, 0), (<app.Message object at 0x103f42e48>, 0), (<app.Message object at 0x103f688d0>, 0), (<app.Message object at 0x103f68588>, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using properly the `@hybrid_attribute`. Split your `score` into `like_score` and `dislike_score` to see crazy numbers because the `func.count(...)` you have will basically generate a non-correlated query.

Below should give you an idea how using hybrid can be used for your purpose:

```
class Message(Base):
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def num_likers(self):
        return len(self.likers)

    @num_likers.expression
    def _num_likes_expression(cls):
        return (
            select([func.count('*').label("num_likes_value")])
            .where(like_table.c.message == cls.id)
            .label("num_likers")
        )

    @hybrid_property
    def num_dislikers(self):
        return len(self.dislikers)

    @num_dislikers.expression
    def _num_dislikes_expression(cls):
        return (
            select([func.count('*').label("num_dislikes_value")])
            .where(dislike_table.c.message == cls.id)
            .label("num_dislikers")
        )

    @hybrid_property
    def score(self):
        return self.num_likers - self.num_dislikers
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to read up on that. Also noted that cases when a message had either no likes or no dislikes where dropped so changed the joins to an outerjoin and now it works as intended!  `top_voted_threads = db.session.query(Message, Message.score.label('score')).\
    filter(Message.thread_start == True).\
    outerjoin(Message.likers, Message.dislikers).\
    group_by(Message).order_by('score DESC')[0:10]`

Comment: Great! One tiny thing: I prefer using `order_by(Message.score.desc())` instead of the string as in your example.